# Clarification about how TeX/LaTeX decides it's fully read in a number

Tags: expansion

I started off a bit confused about how `\romannumeral` works.  Then I tried several experiments testing various ways of incorportating numbers into LaTeX and got even more confused.

The following table summarizes some of my experimenting.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{mycounter}
\setcounter{mycounter}{8}
\def\mynumber{8}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{cll}
behavior    & Code                                                   & reults in:                                       \\\hline
as expected & \verb!\ifnum20<\mynumber 2 small\else large\fi!        & \ifnum20<\mynumber 2 small\else large\fi         \\
as expected & \verb!\romannumeral82!                                 & \romannumeral82                                  \\
as expected & \verb!\romannumeral\mynumber 2!                        & \romannumeral\mynumber 2                         \\
as expected & \verb!\ifnum20<\number\mynumber2 small \else large\fi! & \ifnum20<\number\mynumber2 small \else large\fi \\
unexpected  & \verb!\romannumeral\value{mycounter}2!                 & \romannumeral\value{mycounter}2                  \\
unexpected  & \verb!\ifnum1<\value{mycounter}2 small\else large\fi!  & \ifnum1<\value{mycounter}2 small\else large\fi   \\
unexpected  & \verb!\ifnum20<\value{mycounter}2 small\else large\fi! & \ifnum20<\value{mycounter}2 small\else large\fi  \\
unexpected  & \verb!\ifnum100<\number`Q2 small \else large\fi!       & \ifnum100<\number`Q2 small \else large\fi        \\
unexpected  & \verb!\ifnum100<`Q2 small \else large\fi!              & \ifnum100<`Q2 small \else large   \fi            \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Could someone explain how it is that in the bottom six examples `2` is not read in as part of the number testing evaluated or tested?

Comment: `\`Q` is already a finished `<number>` by itself.

Comment: @egreg What are the rules for determining a complete number then?  From my experiments, am I to conclude that `\value{mycounter}` is also a complete number?

Comment: Yes, it is: it expands to `\c@mycounter` which is the internal name for the counter register; any counter register can be used in the context of a `<number>`. However TeX *doesn't* look for a following optional space in this case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The backtick syntax returns the character code of the specified character it consumes the character token and an optional space. It does not construct the decimal representation of that number (to which 2 might possibly be added)

Conversely `\number` *does* return the decimal expansion  so

```
\number\mynumber2
```

expands to 82 and as seen as such in the ifnum test. (`\number` isn't really doing anything there as `\mynumber` would expand to 8 on its own)

Comment: I can't find the documentation on the backtick syntax.  If I'm in an inherently numeric context, do the backtick also return the character code of the following token?  Are there other contexts wheree the backtick returns the character code?  (Certainly not all the time since I often use backtick as a single quotation mark without unexpected results.)

Comment: @A.Ellett a backtick typesets as a quotation mark in a typesetting context just as `2` typesets as 2. They are only treated differently when TeX is looking for a <number> so typically in primitive register assignments and tests

Comment: @A.Ellett See section 7.2 in TeX by Topic.

Comment: When TeX is looking for an integer it expands things. When those things produce digits it keeps looking for more digits until a nondigit occurs, expanding as it goes. This explains all your "unexpected" results, provided you remember that `\number` produces digits, latex's `\value` produces an (unexpandable) count register, and the backtick notation is unexpandable.